# running maven sonar from unix

Tags: maven, unix, sonar-runner

I have a mvn project. I want to run it against sonar.

e.g. the following command - `mvn org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar`

Without going in and modifying the application pom file to add sonar plugin, is there another way that I can call the mvn command and reference sonar plugin ?

Comment: You don't need to touch the pom to execute the sonar-maven-plugin. Just execute the command-line that you mentionned.

Comment: but the command i have executed above is not found because the plugin is not defined in the pom.... hence the question .....

Comment: no, maven plugins do not need to be defined in pom in order to be executed from command-line. Please attach your full maven logs.

Comment: It says the command given is invalid because maven does not know or have the plugin for the sonar scan. I was thinking i could define in the settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it works, but if you execute it from Jenkins with the Sonar plugin it will work without modifying your pom.xml.